# Gradle script execution semantics

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am trying to understand how exactly is the following Gradle script executed:

```
task loadTestData(dependsOn: ['fakeTask', createSchema])
```

I assume that:

- `loadTestData` is a method call
- `dependsOn` is a named argument

But on which object is the method called?

Comment: there are no named arguments in groovy.  this is a map ("short" for `...Data([dependsOn: ...])`

Comment: Also, Gradle uses AST transforms so sometimes there may not be a 1-1 relationship with the final code that is executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually a [Task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html) is being executed as part of gradle build workflow. Tasks in gradle get no parameters but can operate on the system/environment/build variables.

Then `dependsOn` which is a property of the Task gets the tasks the declared defined task is dependent on.
In this case you declare that `task loadTestData` is dependent on tasks `fakeTask` and `createSchema`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but how exactly is it executed? What kind of method chain?

Comment: This is based on gradle engine for calculating the execution script and executing it. Generally the stack trace would generally be very very long (with ~100 calls) due to the many delegates being called along the way. In order to see the stack trace you can simply add `throw new exception()` to your task and execute gradlew with the `--full-stacktrace` flag.